# Adding "hoverIntent" to .live function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Real simple question here - how do I add the [.hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) from Brian Cherne to the following code in place of the `.live("hover", function`

```
        $(".highlight").live("hover", function(){
            $(this).animate({"width": "454px", "height":"282px", "top: ":"94px", "left":"152px", "margin-top: ":"-94px", "margin-left":"-152px"}, 500);       

        });
```

Here's the full code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){         

        $('#sliding_grid li').hover(function() {
          $(this).css('z-index',1).data('origTop',$(this).css('top')).data('origLeft',$(this).css('left')).addClass('highlight');

        }, function() {
          $(this).css('z-index', 0);
        });

        $(".highlight").live("hover", function(){
            $(this).animate({"width": "454px", "height":"282px", "top: ":"94px", "left":"152px", "margin-top: ":"0", "margin-left":"0"}, 500);       

        });   

        $(".highlight").live("mouseout", function(){
            $(this).animate({"width": "148px", "height":"90px", "top: ":$(this).data('origTop'), "left":$(this).data('origLeft'), "margin-top: ":"0", "margin-left":"0"}, 500, function(){
             $(this).removeClass('highlight');   
            });        

        });        

    });
```

Comment: hernan on github forked it and added support to the plugin so it binds to the live event without changing any of your code. https://github.com/hernan/hoverIntent commit - https://github.com/hernan/hoverIntent/commit/c35a71a92278792d70845c711c41c5b9e909b848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function animateFn(){
     $(this).animate({"width": "454px", "height":"282px", "top: ":"94px", "left":"152px", "margin-top: ":"-94px", "margin-left":"-152px"},200);
}

function reseteFn(){ 
    $(this).animate({"width": "148px", "height":"90px", "top: ":$(this).data('origTop'), "left":$(this).data('origLeft'), "margin-top: ":"0", "margin-left":"0"}, 500, function(){
         $(this).removeClass('highlight');   
    });
}

var config = {    
     over: animateFn, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
     timeout: 200, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
     out: reseteFn // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
};

$(".highlight").hoverIntent(config)
```

Comment: I'm going to check it out in 5 mins ;) I'll let you know

Comment: Where's hoverintent lib? Also, the code is wrong. You have to set '$(".highlight").hoverIntent(config);' instead of '$(".highlight").live("mouseout", function(){...'

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/ZZDdR/ check this out! It needs some z-index and offset fixes, but seems to work ;) p.s. the plugin is added through "Add Resources" on the left

Comment: hernan on github forked it and added support to the plugin so it binds to the live event without changing any of your code. https://github.com/hernan/hoverIntent commit - https://github.com/hernan/hoverIntent/commit/c35a71a92278792d70845c711c41c5b9e909b848

Comment: @jBeas this deserves to be written in a separate answer, not hidden in the read more comments.

Answer (score 6):

As of this answer, the current version of the plugin is "r7" which can be found here:

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.r7.js

With version "r7", you can pass a selector as the third parameter. This is like the [delegate event](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in jQuery. When adding hoverIntent to a list of dynamic elements, bind the hoverIntent event to the parent element and use the third parameter to add a selector of the element you want to use the hoverIntent on.

For example, if you have a list of `<li>` elements that will be changing and you want the hoverIntent to fire on each `<li>` then you can do the following:

```
$("ul").hoverIntent(overFunction, outFunction, "li");
```

This is very basic so you would want to update the 2 selectors to match your exact setup.

Comment: ++++ You wouldn't believe how many posts I've had to read/try-out before finding your totally amazing answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped you out Matthew!

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing this code:

```
$(".highlight").live("hover", function(){
    $(this).animate({"width": "454px", "height":"282px", "top: ":"94px", "left":"152px", "margin-top: ":"0", "margin-left":"0"}, 500);       

});
```

With this:

```
$('.highlight').live('mouseover', function() {  
  if (!$(this).data('init')) {  
    $(this).data('init', true);  
    $(this).hoverIntent(function(){  
      $(this).animate({"width": "454px", "height":"282px", "top: ":"94px", "left":"152px", "margin-top: ":"0", "margin-left":"0"}, 500);
    },  
    function(){  
      /* mouseout logic */  
    });  
    $(this).trigger('mouseover');  
  }  
});
```

[Source](http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/02/jquery-live-and-plugins.html)

Comment: Thats a really ugly method of handling this.  Not going to say it won't work... but it makes me want to cry. :)

Comment: Not working :(  Here is your code plugged into the source: http://jsfiddle.net/kTFvj/4/