# How to get jQuery dialog to wait before displaying?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like my jQuery dialog to display exactly 3 seconds after a user hovers over an image. Currently I have:

```
$(".imgLi").live('hover', function() {
    showDialog();
});

function showDialog()
{
    $('#imageDialogDiv').dialog({
        modal:true
    });
}

<div id="imageDialogDiv" title="Blah">...</div>
```

Not sure where too put the time code or how to implement jQuery's timer object here. If the use "mouses away" (moves the mouse away from the image) at any point during that 3 second timeframe, I *do not* want the dialog to display. Thanks in advance for any help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, I added a cleartimeout on mouseout so it shouldn't execute if the user mouses away

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".imgLi", function() {
    var t=setTimeout("showDialog()",3000);
}).on('mouseleave', ".imgLi", function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
});

function showDialog()
{
    $('#imageDialogDiv').dialog({
        modal:true
    });
}

<div id="imageDialogDiv" title="Blah">...</div>
```

Comment: This will show the dialog in 3 seconds even if the user mouses away, which is not what the OP wants. Also better to do `setTimeout(showDialog, 3000)`

Comment: Ya I missed that, so I added a clearTimeout, that should take care of it.

Comment: `t` is declared in `timedCount()` scope, so won't be accessible in `mouseout` handler. Also you parameters to `.live()` are wrong. It will cause a syntax error.

Comment: ya I fixed it, On should be used anyways because live is deprecated.  Either way I think your answer was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".imgLi").live({
        mouseenter:
           function()
           {
              window.myTimeout = setTimeout(showDialog,3000);
           },
        mouseleave:
           function()
           {
              clearTimeout(window.myTimeout);
           }
       }
    );

function showDialog()
{
    $('#imageDialogDiv').dialog({
        modal:true
    });
}
```

Simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/weCpE/

Answer (score 1):

You can show the dialog after 3 seconds of hover and if the user mouses away before the 3 seconds, it will not show using this type of code.

I also migrated the code to use `.on()` because `.live()` has been deprecated in all versions of jQuery.  You should replace `document` in this code with a static parent element that is closer to the `".imgLi"` objects for better performance.

```
var dialogTimer = null;
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".imgLi", function() {
    if (!dialogTimer) {
        dialogTimer = setTimeout(function() {
             dialogTimer = null;
             showDialog();
        }, 3000);
    }
}).on('mouseleave', ".imgLi", function() {
    if (dialogTimer) {
        clearTimeout(dialogTimer);
        dialogTimer = null;
    }
});

function showDialog()
{
    $('#imageDialogDiv').dialog({
        modal:true
    });
}

<div id="imageDialogDiv" title="Blah">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin from Brian Cherne with excellent results - you can easily configure it to the exact delay you want. I don't think it works with `.live` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727099/adding-hoverintent-to-live-function)).